# How to enable split horizontal/vertical shortcut on WezTerm?

Tags: terminal

I'm on macOS, and my default terminal app is WezTerm (20240203-110809-5046fc22 installed).

[image]

Is there a shortcut to do horizontal/vertical split from a right click, so I don't have to access the menu bar?

You can do it easily on iTerm, like this:

[image]